# Regex to remove all quoted numbers in a df column, leaving the remainder

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

A column in an R dataframe shows the number of times each option on a multiple-choice quiz was selected. One row in the column looks like this:

```
{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}
```

This means:
Choice 1 was selected 74 times.
Choice 2 was selected 371 times.
Choice 3 was selected 22 times.
Choice 4 was selected 62 times.
Choice 5 was selected 22 times.

I want to sum up the number of times all choices were selected for this question:    (74+371+22+62+22 = 551)

I tried (unsuccessfully) to remove the digit in quotes and colon, but would still need to remove the brackets and sum the remaining comma-separated numbers

```
str_remove(({"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8,"":1}), (\\"[d]\\":\\) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example of your desired output.

Comment: I don't know R, but I expect the following Ruby code could be easily translated: `require 'json'; JSON.parse('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}').values.sum
 #=> 551` (which could be shortened to `JSON.parse('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}').sum(&:last)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner using the package `stringr` that provides the sought sums:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(lapply(str_extract_all(df$a, "(?<=:)\\d+"), as.numeric), sum)
[1] 551 353 529
```

Data (thanks to @Onyambu):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}', 
                       '{"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8}', 
                       '{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62}'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` option.  The regex is extracting (in words) "any collection of one or more digits that are proceeded by a colon".  This gives a string with the four counts.  `tidyr::unnest` splits the string into four separate counts, then it's just converting those values to numeric (from character) and `sum`ming.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}', '{"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8}'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  mutate(numbers = str_extract_all(a, '(?<=:)\\d{1,}')) %>% 
  mutate(question_numbers = str_extract_all(a, '(?<=")\\d{1,}')) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(numbers) %>% 
  mutate(numbers = as.numeric(numbers),
         question_numbers = rep(c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"), nrow(df))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(values_from = numbers, names_from = question_numbers) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(c(one, two, three, four, five), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  a                                                   one   two three  four  five total
  <chr>                                             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 "{\"1\":74,\"2\":371,\"3\":22,\"4\":62,\"5\":22}"    74   371    22    62    22   551
2 "{\"1\":18,\"2\":92,\"3\":232,\"4\":3,\"5\":8}"      18    92   232     3     8   353
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I still need to pivot_wider (somehow) back the numbers so that each row of the original df has a total number of attempts for that question (rather than 5 rows for each question, if that makes sense).

Comment: @CLS, I've edited the answer to deal with multiple input strings and to use `pivot_wider`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without using any library as well.

```
df = data.frame(a = '{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}')
df$b = apply(as.data.frame(df$a), 1, function(x){
        x = gsub('[{}":,]', ' ', x)
        x = as.numeric(strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]])
        x = x[!is.na(x)]
        val = 0
        i = 0
        while (i < length(x)) {
            i = i + 2
            val = val + x[i]
        }
        return(val)
    })

> df
                                      a   b
1 {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22} 551
```

Comment: Thanks - I get an 'Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : object 's' not found

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

str_replace_all('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}', '[{"}]', '') %>% 
  str_split(',') %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  str_split(':') %>% 
  map(~{.x[[2]][1]}) %>% 
  as.numeric() %>% 
  sum()

#> [1] 551
```

---

**New Edit**

Or maybe you are looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

  
txt <- str_replace_all('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}', '[{"}]', '') %>% 
  str_split(',') %>% unlist()

data.frame(t=txt) %>% 
  separate(t, into = c('Question', 'Choices'))
#>   Question Choices
#> 1        1      74
#> 2        2     371
#> 3        3      22
#> 4        4      62
#> 5        5      22
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have is a valid `javascript/python` object.

**javascript object (json)**

```
cbind(df,sm = sapply(df$a,function(x)do.call(sum,jsonlite::fromJSON(x)),USE.NAMES = FALSE))
                                      a  sm
1 {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22} 551
2   {"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8} 353
3        {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62} 529
```

since both of those are vectorized, you could also collapse your strings:

```
y <- sprintf("[%s]", paste(df$a, collapse = ","))
cbind(df, sm = rowSums(jsonlite::fromJSON(y), na.rm = TRUE))
                                      a  sm
1 {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22} 551
2   {"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8} 353
3        {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62} 529
```

**python object:**

```
cbind(df,sm = sapply(df$a,function(x)do.call(sum,reticulate::py_eval(x)),USE.NAMES = FALSE))
                                      a  sm
1 {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22} 551
2   {"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8} 353
3        {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62} 529
```

**regex: base R**

```
x <- gsub(".*?:(\\d+)\\D*","\\1 ",df$a)
cbind(df, sm = rowSums(read.table(text = x, fill = TRUE), na.rm =TRUE))
                                      a  sm
1 {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22} 551
2   {"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8} 353
3        {"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62} 529
```

**tidyverse**

```
df %>% 
   rowid_to_column("grp") %>%
   separate_rows(a, sep = "[^,]+:|[,}]",convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   summarise(sm = sum(a, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    grp    sm
  <int> <int>
1     1   551
2     2   353
3     3   529
```

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62,"5":22}', 
                    '{"1":18,"2":92,"3":232,"4":3,"5":8}', 
                    '{"1":74,"2":371,"3":22,"4":62}'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```